# How to develop distributable UI controls for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I would like to develop a reusable UI control for iPhone. How should I go about doing this? When I say reusable I mean it's packaged in a dll (or whatever is used on iPhone platform)  so it can be reused on multiple projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While dynamic libraries are not allowed to be used in iPhone applications that are to be sold on the iPhone App Store, here's a tutorial on [building static libraries with the iPhone SDK.](http://www.stormyprods.com/blogger/2008/11/using-static-libraries-with-iphone-sdk.html)  (assuming you don't want to release source code)

Comment: Thanks for this link. Exactly what I was thinking but didn't know how to do.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to provide [custom Interface Builder objects](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/developertools/conceptual/IB_UserGuide/CustomizingInterfaceBuilder/chapter_11_section_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005344-CH16-SW12), or maybe source code libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Supply the full source code. Other developers can then add it directly to their app.
2. Distribute the compiled version of your code as a static library.

As you're planning to develop a UI control, I suggest you also develop an IB plugin and ship that with it too.

Comment: IB plug-ins aren't supported for iPhone development.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the Xcode way would be to bundle your code into a Framework and link to that. However, under the iPhone you can't link to non Apple approved frameworks (even if they are your own)

So you would probably have to link in the source to the reusable code. [A good article here](http://blog.omnigroup.com/2008/10/01/using-frameworks-in-iphone-applications/)

Comment: Does this mean that something like Rhodes is not permissible: http://rhomobile.com/wiki/index.php?title=Rhodes

Comment: NO it should work. From the FAQ: The iPhone development terms do not disallow interpreted languages. They disallow interpreting code that has been downloaded independent of both Apple's official distributions channels (i.e. not contained in the app bundle) and Apple's own code.